# What will happen if i change the api name of the data categories in salesforce?

Tags: community, data-category

I wanted to change the api name of the data categories in my org and Salesforce don't recommend moving, deleting or changing the developer name of categories. So I just wanted to know will it affect the knowledge articles? As I know we need to change the API names everywhere in the apex where we are using but I just wanted to know the effect with the knowledge articles.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello , Could you please review this article for the same [Modifying and arranging categories can result in long processing times, changes to the visibility and categorization of articles](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.category_modify.htm&type=5)  , does this answer your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the API name of a data category can impact the Knowledge articles that are associated with it. The articles' data category assignments are stored based on the API name of the data category, so if you change the API name, the articles will no longer be assigned to that data category.

You will need to update the data category assignments for each affected article to reflect the new API name.

Reference - [Modifying and arranging categories can result in long processing times, changes to the visibility and categorization of articles](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.category_modify.htm&type=5)